# php postgresql - error in my request when i'm trying to insert a string

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to customize my ERP which works with a PostgreSQL db with some php files.
-When I'm displaying results with a select query, everything is running perfectly and I get results.
-When I insert Default values or integer, I don't get errors and the insertion work well.  However, when I try to insert string I always get an error.

display.php

```
<?php
$dbconn = pg_connect("host='x.X.x.X' port='x' 
dbname='x' user='x' password='x'") or 
die("unable to connect database");
$query = 'SELECT * FROM "OpenConcerto48"."CLIENT" ';
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
if (!$result) {
echo null;
exit;
}
$resultArray = pg_fetch_all($result);
echo json_encode($resultArray);
pg_close ($dbconn);
?>
```

insert.php

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host='x.X.X.X' port='x' dbname='x' user='x' 
password='x'") or die("unable to connect database");

$a = pg_escape_string('sarl') ;

//Insertion in db work well when values are "default" or integer and i get this error :  ERREUR: la colonne « test » n'existe pas LINE 3: VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT, "test", DEFAULT) ^
$query = 'INSERT INTO "OpenConcerto48"."CLIENT"
("ID","FORME_JURIDIQUE","NOM","CODE")
VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT, 58, DEFAULT)';

//Insertion don't work when i try to insert a string
$query = 'INSERT INTO "OpenConcerto48"."CLIENT"
("ID","FORME_JURIDIQUE","NOM","CODE")
VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT, "test", DEFAULT)';

if (pg_query($dbconn,$query))
{
echo "saved";
}
else
{
echo "error insering data  ";
echo pg_last_error($dbconn);
//echo pg_last_error($query);
}
```

The problem is when I insert a string, it considers it as a column and I get an error.
ps : I have many schema in my database and I'm working on the schema openconcerto48 on table client.

Comment: what error you get and in what line?

Comment: use single quotes instead of double quotes around the string values

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : thank you for your reply, the error is : ERREUR: la colonne « test » n'existe pas LINE 3: VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT, "test", DEFAULT) ^. he is considering test as a column in the table. the error is in the query especially with the double quotes

Comment: @KarstenKoop i tried with simple quotes, double quotes, $ $. never works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead if

```
 VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT, "test", DEFAULT)';
```

use single quotes:

```
 VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT, 'test', DEFAULT)';
```

Also is weird in previous query you have

```
 VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT, 58, DEFAULT)';
```

So if 58 is also a string you should use `'58'`

Try **[PHP DEMO](http://rextester.com/CBUZ31757)**:

```
<?php //php 7.0.8

    $query = 'INSERT INTO "OpenConcerto49"."CLIENT" 
("ID","FORME_JURIDIQUE","NOM","CODE") VALUES 
(DEFAULT,DEFAULT,\'test\', DEFAULT)';

    echo $query;

?>
```

Comment: when i use single quote i get this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'test' (T_STRING) in .../insert.php on line 9.  when i insert an integer exemple : 59 in work but when i write '58' between  simple quotes i get the error of syntaxes and between double quotes i get the error :ERREUR: la colonne « test » n'existe pas LINE 3: VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT, "58", DEFAULT) ^

Comment: What data type is `NOM` ?

Comment: your PHP-String is also in single quotes, so you have to either escape the inner quotes, or use double quotes in PHP.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, NOM data type is character varying

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, i've tried : $query ="INSERT INTO \"OpenConcerto49\".\"CLIENT\"
(\"ID\",\"FORME_JURIDIQUE\",\"NOM\",\"CODE\")
    VALUES ( DEFAULT,DEFAULT,'test5yosri', DEFAULT )";   and it worked for me.tyvm

Comment: Did you see the demo. I use single quotes `

Comment: Yes i tried it, it worked perfectly also. tyvm again for the help @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Remember accept the answer clicking the Thick on the the answer

Answer (score 0):

@KarstenKoop,
i tried :

```
$a = 'sarl';
$query = 'INSERT INTO "OpenConcerto49"."CLIENT" 
("ID","FORME_JURIDIQUE","NOM","CODE") VALUES 
(DEFAULT,DEFAULT,pg_escape_string('.$a.'), DEFAULT)';
```

got this error :

```
ERREUR: la colonne « sarl » n'existe pas LINE 3: VALUES(DEFAULT,DEFAULT,pg_escape_string(sarl), DEFAULT) ^ –
```